# Ivy Eclipse plugin - where is the default repository defined?

Tags: plugins, repository, ivy

I'm using Ivy Plugin for Eclipse. Dependencies are being downloaded from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. Where is this defined? I have found some ivy jars under plugins directory and looked inside those jars but haven't found anything that contains this link.

Answer (score 0):

It's a constant in the source code for the default ibiblio resolver:

- [IBiblioResolver class](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant-ivy.git;a=blob;f=src/java/org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/IBiblioResolver.java;h=8072e3f352a0ff9ed42a909be796aeaa6b83ada3;hb=0b9db35ee7a94a719e538b04122b86cb997f3a17#l72)